# Is there a way to force the format of a README.txt file on github?

Tags: git, github, restructuredtext

I uploaded some code to github with a README.txt file that's in ReStructuredText format. Is there a way to instruct github to format this file as rest instead of just plain text?

Comment: Not that I know of, you need to name the file the appropriate way so that it be rendered like you intend it to.

Comment: `README.md` for Markdown, `README.textile` for Textile, etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file name should end in `rest, rst, rest.txt or rst.txt`

https://github.com/github/markup

Comment: The README there only documents `.rst` but the [actual code](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/1e7d83fd1e605db9f0d975482c2891a19bfeaf6b/lib/github/markups.rb#L33) matches `/re?st(\.txt)?/`.  Searching github shows [README.rst](https://github.com/search?p=100&q=filename%3AREADME.rst+extension%3Arst&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) is vastly more popular than  [README.rest](https://github.com/search?p=18&q=filename%3AREADME.rest+extension%3Arest&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).